My nvidia quadro k620 stopped working
I took out my gpu so i can test another one and when I wanted to put it back I just heard some beeping noises there is one pin shorter than the others but the back has all the pins alined.

Everything breaks. Or you forgot to reconnect the additional power cable, if applicable. I wonder what kind of answer are you expecting?

Pins are different lengths on purpose, usually to protect particularly sensitive pathways from electrical issues. So a pin being a different length is not an indication of any problem, on its own.
